# Not able import redis rdb backup from S3 to Elasticache in the same account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am not able to import redis rdb backup file from S3 to Elasticache in the same account.

Getting an error "Failed to retrieve from S3" in the events page of Elasticache.

I have added this canonical Id : Canonical ID: 540804c33a284a299d2547575ce1010f2312ef3da9b3a053c8bc45bf233e4353 according to this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elasticache-restore-cluster-from-s3/#:%7E:text=in%20DB%200.-,ElastiCache%20couldn%27t%20retrieve%20the%20file%20from%20Amazon%20S3,issue%20by%20reviewing%20ElastiCache%20Events.) in the S3 bucket policy.

Region is eu-central-1

Still I am not able to fix the issue.

I have cluster mode disabled in both source and destination.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant ElastiCache read access to the .rdb file. Since `eu-central-1` is a default region, we can follow the documentation for [granting ElastiCache read access in default region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups-seeding-redis.html#backups-seeding-redis-grant-access).

Note that changes need to be made to the Bucket's Access Control List (ACL) and not to the bucket policy.

You can do that using the aws cli:

```
# Set the bucket name
export BUCKET=<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>

# Get the current bucket policy
aws s3api get-bucket-acl --bucket $BUCKET > $BUCKET-acl.json

# Add the grantee for ElastiCache using jq
cat $BUCKET-acl.json | jq '.Grants += [{
  "Grantee": {
      "Type": "CanonicalUser",
      "ID": "540804c33a284a299d2547575ce1010f2312ef3da9b3a053c8bc45bf233e4353"
  },
  "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
}]' > $BUCKET-modified-acl.json

# Modify the Bucket's ACL
aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket $BUCKET --access-control-policy file://$BUCKET-modified-acl.json

# Remove the temporary json files
rm $BUCKET-acl.json $BUCKET-modified-acl.json
```

Comment: Yes, it is Bucket ACL, my bad. I have that access already in place. I have added external account canonical id with 540804c33a284a299d2547575ce1010f2312ef3da9b3a053c8bc45bf233e4353 in s3 bucket ACL with list and write permissions. Still no luck.